# Burst mode data errors on I2C

Tags: i2c, noise, stm32

I'm using burst mode to read 14 bytes from a sensor via I2C running at 400KHz. The problem is that there are periodic errors on the last byte of the packet, that come in roughly every 8 reads. The issue does seem to be specifically related to the last byte, as a current workaround is to simply request 15 bytes instead of 14 (there are registers after the ones i care about, so that works fine).

What could possibly cause this? A couple of things that I'm uncertain about:

- the pull-up resistors are 4.7K. I know this is on the threshold of sizing for 400KHz, but switching to smaller resistors doesn't seem to have an impact (tried 3.3, 2.5 and 1.5)
- There are what appear to be irregularities in the clock line (see attached logic analyzer screenshot). I'm not sure if that's something or not, but I would expect a clock line to be... well - regular.

I'm using the hardware I2C driver on an STM32 chip.

LA output:
[image]

Comment: What's the device?

Comment: Is it always the last byte?  So out of 14 bytes, it's the 14th.  Out of 15 bytes it is the 15th?  Out of 8 bytes, it's the 8th?

Comment: Yes, it seems to always be the last byte.

Comment: Definitely some weirdness between the 9th and 10th clocks, with SDA doing that 0-1-0 transition. Also some stretching on the 19th clock, which also seems odd to me (I usually expect stretching on the ACK/NACK pulses, which #19 shouldn't be.)

Comment: Do you have your logic analyzer set to the correct voltage threshold? The on-time of the SCL pulses seems small to me.

Comment: re: voltage threshold - i think so? i'll recheck. i'm more of a software guy typically.

Comment: Can you post your I2C read code? The ordering of calls before the last byte is very important. And remember to clear flags by reading the SR2 register.